# Get next function without waiting for the end of eternal cycle

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, async-await

I have function, which start new task:

```
private async Task GetCamera()
{
  ....
  await Task.Run(async () => await MyAwesomeTask());//eternal cycle
  int a=10;//how start without waiting for the end of the thread?
  int b=15;
  SomeFunction(a,b);    
}

private async Task MyAwesomeTask()
{
  while (true)
  {
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));
    //some task
  }
}
```

But next line (int a=10;) wait when Task will end. I need, that (int a=10;) **NOT** wait and go next. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you await your Task.Run(...) call the execution of your GetCamera method is 'paused' on the await line until the Task has finished. As soon as the asynchronous call terminates the execution of the GetCamera method continues.

> The await operator is applied to a task in an asynchronous method to suspend the execution of the method until the awaited task completes. The task represents ongoing work.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh156528.aspx)

To let your method continue execution you need to remove that await.